# Call setCentralWidget from other file

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have different files (main.py and layout.py) and I want to change the windows (I have shortened the example that it should change the window size) of QMainWindow from the file layout.py.

It works fine from main.py, I can change the windows from the file main.py, but it has no effect in layout.py.

UPDATE: I changed the files two a working example with the problem that the Button "Switch to Layout 2" does not work.

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction, QApplication, QMainWindow
from layout import Layout1, Layout2

class MainClass(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
    super(MainClass, self).__init__()

    def initUI(self):
    self.setGeometry(50, 100, 600, 500)
    self.setWindowTitle('program')


    self.window1Action = QAction('Window1', self)
    self.window1Action.triggered.connect(self.window1)
    self.window2Action = QAction('Window2', self)
    self.window2Action.triggered.connect(self.window2)

    self.menubar = self.menuBar()
    menu = self.menubar.addMenu('&Menu')
    menu.addAction(self.window1Action)
    menu.addAction(self.window2Action)

    self.show()

    def window1(self):
    wsize1 = (1200, 600)
    self.resize(*wsize1)
    self.form_widget = Layout1()
    self.setCentralWidget(self.form_widget)

    def window2(self):
    wsize2 = (600, 500)
    self.resize(*wsize2)
    self.form_widget = Layout2()
    self.setCentralWidget(self.form_widget)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainClass()
    ex.initUI()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**layout.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFormLayout, QPushButton, QWidget

class Layout1(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(Layout1, self).__init__(parent)

    self.form_layout = QFormLayout(self)

    self.button1 = QPushButton('Button1')
    self.form_layout.addRow('nonfunctional', self.button1)

    self.buttonX = QPushButton('Switch to Layout2')
    self.form_layout.addRow('Problem', self.buttonX)
    self.buttonX.clicked.connect(self.change_layout)

    self.setLayout(self.form_layout)

    def change_layout(self):
    from main import MainClass
    self.change_window = MainClass()
    self.change_window.window2()


class Layout2(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(Layout2, self).__init__(parent)

    self.form_layout = QFormLayout(self)

    self.button2 = QPushButton('Button3')
    self.form_layout.addRow('nonfunctional', self.button2)

    self.setLayout(self.form_layout)
```

Can anybody explain to me what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Layout classes have a `parent` parameter, so use it. You need to get a reference to the *existing instance* of the main window, not create a new one:

```
    def window1(self):
        ...
        self.form_widget = Layout1(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.form_widget)

    ...        

    def change_layout(self):
        self.parent().window2()
```